# Releasing memory for objects added using Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a situation where I build a view with a table and another view for table header (containing images and labels and buttons). Now I connected the table, image, labels, buttons to variables in my Controller class. Should I release the memory in `-dealloc` method for all those variables that I connected using Interface Builder? I believe memory is automatically allocated for these variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is best provided by [Apple's Memory Management of Nib Objects](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemMgmtNibObjects.html) document. If your code "owns" the NIB (i.e. you called `+[NSBundle loadNibNamed: foo owner: bar]`) then your code needs to destroy the NIB resources.

Comment: Updated link: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html

Comment: Key sentence: "Objects in the nib file are created with a retain count of 1 and then autoreleased."